# Dump JSON from pandas dataframe by unique column1 column2 combination

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have some data in an SQL database that I'm looking to convert to JSON.  For every unique combination of grp1 and grp2, I'd like for it to list grp1, grp2 and name.  I guess the correct terminology is nested JSON?

Here's my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

json_string = '[{"grp1":"aaa","grp2":"streets","name":"Carter"},{"grp1":"aaa","grp2":"streets","name":"Chestnut"},{"grp1":"aaa","grp2":"streets","name":"Main"},{"grp1":"aaa","grp2":"aaa","name":"aaa"},{"grp1":"aaa","grp2":"ramps","name":"Ramp_A"},{"grp1":"aaa","grp2":"ramps","name":"Ramp_B"},{"grp1":"aaa","grp2":"ramps","name":"Ramp_C"},{"grp1":"test1","grp2":"test2","name":"testname"}]'

a_json = json.loads(json_string)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a_json)
print(df)

g = df.groupby(['grp1', 'grp2']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
g['combo'] = g['grp1'] + '-' + g['grp2']
print(g)
```

How can I utilize json.dumps to spit out the following nested JSON?

```
{
  "groups": [
  {
    "title": "aaa-aaa",
    "items": [
      {
         "title": "aaa",
         "combo3": "aaa-aaa-aaa"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "aaa-streets",
    "items": [
      {
         "title": "Carter",
         "combo3": "aaa-streets-Carter"
      },
      {
         "title": "Chestnut",
         "combo3": "aaa-streets-Chestnut"
      },
      {
         "title": "Main",
         "combo3": "aaa-streets-Main"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "aaa-ramps",
    "items": [
      {
         "title": "Ramp_A",
         "combo3": "aaa-ramps-Ramp_A"
      },
      {
         "title": "Ramp_B",
         "combo3": "aaa-ramps-Ramp_B"
      },
      {
         "title": "Ramp_C",
         "combo3": "aaa-ramps-Ramp_C"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "test1-test2",
    "items": [
      {
         "title": "testname",
         "combo3": "test1-test2-testname"
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to collect the items and map them to a temporary dictionary before eventually converting them to json-format.

Here is the running code:

```
json_string = '[{"grp1":"aaa","grp2":"streets","name":"Carter"},{"grp1":"aaa","grp2":"streets","name":"Chestnut"},{"grp1":"aaa","grp2":"streets","name":"Main"},{"grp1":"aaa","grp2":"aaa","name":"aaa"},{"grp1":"aaa","grp2":"ramps","name":"Ramp_A"},{"grp1":"aaa","grp2":"ramps","name":"Ramp_B"},{"grp1":"aaa","grp2":"ramps","name":"Ramp_C"},{"grp1":"test1","grp2":"test2","name":"testname"}]'

a_json = json.loads(json_string)
df = pd.DataFrame(a_json)

df['title'] = df['grp1'] + '-' + df['grp2']
df['combo3'] = df['grp1'] + '-' + df['grp2'] + '-' + df['name']

result_json = df[['title', 'name', 'combo3']].groupby(['title'])\
    .apply(lambda x: x[['name', 'combo3']].rename(columns={'name': 'title'}).to_dict('r'))\
    .reset_index()\
    .rename(columns={0:'items'})\
    .to_json(orient='records')

print(result_json)
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "title": "aaa-aaa",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "aaa",
        "combo3": "aaa-aaa-aaa"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "aaa-ramps",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Ramp_A",
        "combo3": "aaa-ramps-Ramp_A"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ramp_B",
        "combo3": "aaa-ramps-Ramp_B"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ramp_C",
        "combo3": "aaa-ramps-Ramp_C"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "aaa-streets",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Carter",
        "combo3": "aaa-streets-Carter"
      },
      {
        "name": "Chestnut",
        "combo3": "aaa-streets-Chestnut"
      },
      {
        "name": "Main",
        "combo3": "aaa-streets-Main"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "test1-test2",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "testname",
        "combo3": "test1-test2-testname"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it gets me 95% of the way there.  Is it possible to have a group title called "title" and also have "title" inside the group's items (rather than "name"?  I realize it is a bit unusual to have it this way.  I tried renaming "name" to "title" and got a ValueError: Grouper for 'title' not 1-dimensional

Comment: @Rayner you can rename the column while you convert it to the dict. Edited the answer to do that.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks.  I've been trying for 3 days to learn enough about pandas, dictionaries and json to get this to work.  Last thing, and I'll accept your answer: How do you encapsulate the json results with {   \n  "groups": [ ] }  rather than a single [ ]

Comment: Just wrap it in a dictionary :) Something like `dict_res = {'group': json_results} ; print(dict_res)`

Comment: Sorry, I tried with single quotes and double quotes, resulting json gives an error when validating, Parse error on line 1: {'group': '[{"title":  Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined' and the error arrow is pointing to the single quote before the word 'group'

Comment: ```dict_res = { 'group' : json.loads(result_json) }``` yields the ```dict```.  Then ```json.dump(dict_res, [some file opened for writing])```.

Comment: Thanks @NateB, that worked perfectly.  I used the following to get it to create the JSON file with pretty printing:

`with open('answer.js', 'w') as f:
    j = json.dump(dict_res, f, indent=2)`